# How do I modify my .gitignore file by adding !*.css at the end?

Tags: gitignore

I'm new to pulling/pushing code and gitignore, and I can't figure out how to modify the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
echo "!*.css" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Whitelist css files"
git push -u origin master
```

That would update your `.gitignore` file.